# How to merge vertically two strings obtained through grep?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am using the `grep` command to select some fields into a file. This command selects N (N=2 in the example below) blocks of 5 space-separated fields each, and returns a variable containing this string, called `firstPart`:

```
chr8 aa1 bb1 cc1 dd1 chr8 aa2 bb2 cc2 dd2
```

Also the second `grep` execution returns a string containing N blocks of 5 space-separated fields, called `secondPart`, which contains:

```
SLC7A2 ee1 ff1 gg1 hhh1 SLC7A2 ee2 ff2 gg2 hhh2
```

I would like to know which bash command I could use to put `firstPart` and `secondPart` into an array of N elements where the first block of each element is associated to its corresponding second block. The output should be:

```
chr8 aa1 bb1 cc1 dd1 SLC7A2 ee1 ff1 gg1 hhh1
chr8 aa2 bb2 cc2 dd2 SLC7A2 ee2 ff2 gg2 hhh2
```

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Should be trivial with awk; please show input data and grep command

Comment: The second command seems to return 8 fields total, how is that N blocks of 5 fields?

Comment: I also suspect there is a better way to solve your original problem (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: You may be shooting yourself in the foot by using `$(command substitution)` to create a variable from multi-line grep output. Abstracting your original problem does not help us help you. Please post your raw input.

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do, this is not the way to do it. Post a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output demonstrating **what** you're trying to do rather than **how** you're trying to do it so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: this is answering the question "if I have two string of *N* blocks of 5 blank separated words each, how can I get an array of `N` elements, where each element *i* contains block *i* from the first and the second string?"

There is almost certainly a better way to solve your underlying problem, though. Specifically, my answer is totally independent of how you obtained the strings, but most likely, the whole problem can be solved with a single awk command.

Here's how I would solve what you actually asked, in Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

firstPart='chr8 aa1 bb1 cc1 dd1 chr8 aa2 bb2 cc2 dd2'
secondPart='SLC7A2 ee1 ff1 gg1 hhh1 SLC7A2 ee2 ff2 gg2 hhh2'
N=2
for ((i = 0; i < N; ++i)); do
    printf -v arr[i] '%s %s' \
        "$(cut -d ' ' -f $((1 + i * 5))-$((5 + i * 5)) <<< "$firstPart")" \
        "$(cut -d ' ' -f $((1 + i * 5))-$((5 + i * 5)) <<< "$secondPart")"
done

printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

The `cut` command expands to something like

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1-5
```

for the first blocks, then

```
cutd -d ' ' -f 6-10
```

for the second blocks, and so on. The `printf` statement combines those outputs and stores them in the output array `arr` at index `i`.

The output is

```
chr8 aa1 bb1 cc1 dd1 SLC7A2 ee1 ff1 gg1 hhh1
chr8 aa2 bb2 cc2 dd2 SLC7A2 ee2 ff2 gg2 hhh2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to do but since you already have answers to the question you asked, here's another:

```
$ firstPart='chr8 aa1 bb1 cc1 dd1 chr8 aa2 bb2 cc2 dd2'
$ secondPart='SLC7A2 ee1 ff1 gg1 hhh1 SLC7A2 ee2 ff2 gg2 hhh2'

$ read -r -a fp <<< "$firstPart"
$ read -r -a sp <<< "$secondPart"

$ fmt="$(eval "printf '%%s %.0s' {1..$(( ${#sp[@]} / 2 - 1 ))}")%s\n"

$ paste -d' ' <(printf "$fmt" "${fp[@]}") <(printf "$fmt" "${sp[@]}")
chr8 aa1 bb1 cc1 dd1 SLC7A2 ee1 ff1 gg1 hhh1
chr8 aa2 bb2 cc2 dd2 SLC7A2 ee2 ff2 gg2 hhh2
```